# Importing VStudio 2008 VC++ project into VStudio 2010 ....using MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, objectarx

I am importing a Visual Studio 2008 VC++ project into VStudio 2010. I am using Object arx application, where I need to include their library files. The issue right now is that the library files from the previous version are getting included but not the current version, whereas if I open a new sample project in VStudio 2010, it should include the library files of the current version.....

Any help regarding the same will be highly appreciated....

Comment: The previous version of what? Please clarify. OTOH regardless of fix, I suggest reshape the .vcxproj-s getting rid of conversion props files.

Comment: @BalogPal The versions mentioned above were 2008 and 2010, so was Importing a 2008 Project to a new 2010 Prjoect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't safely link a Visual Studio application to libraries built with a different compiler version. Such attempts always lead to a lot of conflicts and mismatches between different versions of system libraries that both your application and external library depend on.

So, the solution for your problem would be to get a set of ObjectARX library binaries built with Visual Studio 2010. Or rebuild them from source, if it is available.

Also beware of building with the same compiler version, but different options (Multithreaded/Single-Threaded runtime, Debug/Release, static/DLL runtime, iterator debugging level for STL, etc). Such mismatches don't always lead to link-time failures (VS2010 improved its checks a bit, though), but are very likely to cause mysterious crashes in runtime.

Comment: Kiriinyale, gave a good explanation. However I found the solution. it was with the missing libraries required for Object ARX and MFC's. I had to manually add them in the Additional Directories, Include Directories in Properties --> C/C++ folder and Additional Dependenicies in Properties --> Linker --> Input. –